# Problem defining postfix operators in raku REPL

Tags: raku, rakudo

If I have the following program in raku it works well:

```
trabajando-en-piensa-en-raku on  master [?] via  v2.6.5
❯ cat factorial.raku

sub factorial( $n ) {
   [*] 1 .. $n;
}

sub postfix:<!>( $n ) {
    [*] 1 .. $n;
}

my $n = 5;

say "El factorial de $n es {factorial $n}";

say "Si calculamos $n! obtenemos {$n!}";


trabajando-en-piensa-en-raku on  master [?] via  v2.6.5
❯ raku factorial.raku
El factorial de 5 es 120
si calculamos 5! obtenemos 120
```

But if I define this functions in the raku REPL I get:

```
> * * &factorial
> 5
> El factorial de 5 es 120
```

It works normally and as expected for the factorial function, but I get this for the ! operator:

```
> * * &postfix:<!>
> ===SORRY!=== Error while compiling:
Negation metaoperator not followed by valid infix
------> say "Si calculamos $n! obtenemos {$n!⏏}";
    expecting any of:
        infix
        infix stopper
```

I need an special sintax in order to define operators in raku REPL, or is depending how the environment is loaded.

I'm using In OSX Catalina

```
trabajando-en-piensa-en-raku on  master [?] via  v2.6.5
❯ rakubrew versions
  system
  moar-2020.07
* moar-2020.08.2
```

Comment: I'm curious whether you are aware of, and have tried, [CommaIDE](https://commaide.com/) and [its "Integrated REPL"](https://commaide.com/features) (which, like most features, is included in the free Community Edition).

Comment: Well, there is no special reason, I'm an Emacser, so I prefer this editor over intellij Editors (I used intellij many years and I really liked it (java developer) but since I'm started working with rubym my company also paid the RubyMine Lic but I feel that I need new way of working so switched to terminal and Emacs and now I use for every day task).

Comment: Comming from Ruby that Pry is, in my opinion, the best REPL around, I was thinking that raku has something similar but not, it has CommaIDE, it's good, but I would prefer a good LSP (or the tools of ruby ruby-mode (written by ruby creator), inf-ruby which in combination with pry is fantastic and robe-mode) and choose your IDE and a good REPL for working where you want and not inside an IDE. so wht you think @raiph

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid the REPL in its current state, has several deficiencies regarding several Raku features, such as native variables and operator definition, **IF** these are executed in more than one line.

Currently the REPL is basically executing an `EVAL` statement for each line, with not enough information shared between invocations.  This will not change in the short run.  It might get better when the rakuast branch lands, sometime next year.